# Error issuing session token: HostAuthorizationNotFound

Tags: azure-devops, vssdk

Im developing TFS extension using angular and when I debugging the extension I unable to make rest calls using the VSS SDK, it try to make a request to WebPlatformAuth but it throw exception:

> "Error issuing session token: HostAuthorizationNotFound".

Just to make it clear, Im able to use VSS to get WebContext for example project.name or user.id.

(I debug my extension by running ng serve on my localhost and provide the extension manifest "baseUri" field).

*UPDATE* - It happen also when I deploy the extension without the baseUri - not in debug mode.

Just to mention, I also developed another simple extension using only html and jquery and it worked just fine without any additional configurations.

Comment: Can you uninstall and reinstall your extension? Here is a similar ticket and you can refer to it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/issues/9.

Comment: Apparently I just had to enter the manage extensions page and give my extension the authorization to actions it required

Comment: Do you mean you have solved this problem? If yes, would you please turn your comment into an answer and mark it? This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers. Thank you.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling seemed not to help because we switched to a different version of the extension. When I uninstalled and reinstalled the SAME version, the extension worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I just had to enter the 'manage extensions' page at the Azure Devops and give my extension the authorization to the actions it ask for.